# Scrolling window on load

Tags: javascript, html

I submit some values from a form to another page... that page returns with a url like:
localhost:8084/abc.jsp?ok=true

I applied a function on 'onLoad' of my page body named checkscroll()... and this function in javascript should scrolls my window..

CODE: for javascript

```
function checkscroll()
                  {

                     var rr = new String();
                        rr = request.getParametr("ok");
                     if(rr=="true")
                         window.scrollBy(0, 60);

                  }
```

what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: Does `request.getParametr` exist? Is the typo apparent in your real code?

Comment: typo wasn't there in the real code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `location.search`:

```
var qs = location.search;
if (qs.indexOf('ok') >=0 && qs.indexOf('true') >=0) {
  window.scrollBy(0, 60);
}
```

Or

```
var qs = location.search,
         param = qs.split('=')[0].split('?').join(''),
         val = qs.split('=')[1];


if (param === 'ok' && val === 'true') {
  window.scrollBy(0, 60);
}
```

Comment: These are not very pretty solutions. The first one returns true if the strings are apparent *somewhere* in the query string, independent from each other. In the second one `qs.indexOf(param) >= 0` is always true I think because you built `param` by taking part of the query string.

Comment: ty the code is working but can you expain what this 'if (qs.indexOf('ok') >=0 && qs.indexOf('true') >=0)' is doing ?

Comment: @rd4code: In the query string it checks if `ok` var is present and it is set to `true`

Comment: @Sarfraz indexOf is checking the position of ok.. so if i have something like this as my url: localhost:8084/abc.jsp?noook=bytrue.. indexOf will accept ok and true from here

Answer (score 1):

You have used `request.getParametr`, which is a JSP / Java function, not in JavaScript. You need to use `location.search` for getting the parameter.

The code `window.scrollBy(x,y)` works only in Firefox. What browser are you using? For a better compatibility, use jQuery's `animate()` function. To use that, you can try this script.

```
function checkscroll()
{
    var rr = location.search;
    rr = rr.indexOf('ok');
    if(rr=="true")
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 60}, 'slow');
}
```

Let us know, if this solves.

Comment: `indexOf` does not return a string.

Comment: using the answer of @Sarfraz i applied ur jquery in it & its workin quite nice :D... can you expalin what is the meaning of this line:-$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 60}, 'slow');

Comment: It is smooth scrolling of the page using jQuery... Will show you an example here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/